# Javascript Get Value from Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use this for my class homework, I am still learning.

This script is made to check if a site down or not.

What I'm trying to achieve is to use this same script and get statuses for every website on the table without using script all over again all 3 websites.

I added classes but I do not know how to get them to script. I commented on script so it will be easier for you to understand. Any solution for this? Any input would be appreciated.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:250px">Website</th>
            <th style="width:250px">Is it live</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Google</td>                                   

            <td id="website"></td>  <!-- This is already working. -->

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Twitter</td>

            <td id="website" mywebsite="https://Twitter.com"></td> <!-- This is what I'm trying to achive. -->


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Facebook</td>

            
            <td id="website" mywebsite="https://Facebook.com"> <!-- This is what I'm trying to achive. -->

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>





<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var site = 'https://google.com';



    // var site = 'https://google.com';
    
    $.ajax
    ({
      url: site,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      statusCode: {
          200: function (response) {
              $('#website').html('yes');
            console.log(response);
          },
          404: function (response) {
              $('#website').html('no');
            console.log(response);
          }
      } 
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to get the values by class attr? what do you want to do with the ajax? it's confusing.

Comment: Hi, Sorry If I wasn't clear of what I want.  This is script is Ajax. I got it from codepen. What I want is show status for three websites using the same script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:250px">Website</th>
                <th style="width:250px">Is it live</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Google</td>                                   

                <td class="website" data-mywebsite="https://google.com"></td>  <!-- This is already working. -->

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Twitter</td>

                <td class="website" data-mywebsite="https://twitter.com"></td> <!-- This is what I'm trying to achive. -->


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Facebook</td>


                <td class="website" data-mywebsite="https://facebook.com"> </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>



$(document).ready(function(){
         $(".website").each(function(){
           var site = $(this).attr("data-mywebsite");
           var thissr = $(this);

        $.ajax
        ({
          url: site,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          statusCode: {
              200: function (response) {
                  thissr.html('yes');

              },
              404: function (response) {
                  thissr.html('no');

              }
          } 
         });
         });
       });
```

Try this code. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/xpvt214o/108583/)

You need to use class and loop through each of them to send AJAX request.

Comment: I really appreciate this. Thanks in advance for clarification.

Comment: Welcome. :) @RashmiNimesha

Comment: @SmitRaval i am getting no for facebook and twiiter when i can access those sites from my system.

Comment: Ajax call is asynchronous and **thissr** might misbehave

Answer (score 0):

As you know Ajax is an asynchronous call to server,

So if you want to execute ajax call in loop and want to update something based on your ajax call, then you must need a context for which you are calling ajax,

Try something like below,

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:250px">Website</th>
            <th style="width:250px">Is it live</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Google</td>                                   

            <td class="website" data-mywebsite="https://google.com"></td>  <!-- This is already working. -->

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>JQuery</td>

            <td class="website" data-mywebsite="http://jquery.com/"></td> <!-- This is what I'm trying to achive. -->


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Stackoverflow</td>
            <td class="website" data-mywebsite="https://stackoverflow.com/"> <!-- This is what I'm trying to achive. -->

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



$(document).ready(function(){
         $(".website").each(function(){
           var site = $(this).attr("data-mywebsite");
           var thissr = $(this);
                $.ajax
                ({
                  url: site,
                  dataType: "jsonp",
                  context : thissr,
                  statusCode: {
                      200: function (response) {
                          $(this.context).html('yes');

                      },
                      404: function (response) {
                          $(this.context).html('no');

                      }
                  } 
                 });
         });
       });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cdL997a6/1/